# Which website's calorie intake threshold to believe?

Tags: weight, calories

I'm 5'10 (178cm) male who is lightly active and weigh 55kg (122 lbs), and want to maintain this weight, thus have consulted some websites out there that have got 'calorie calculators' to determine the calorie intake per day required to maintain weight. However, the results have varied.

[www.caloriecalculator.net](http://www.calculator.net/calorie-calculator.html?ctype=standard&cage=19&csex=m&cheightfeet=5&cheightinch=10&cpound=121&cheightmeter=180&ckg=60&cactivity=1.375&printit=0&x=88&y=9) and [www.cancer.org](https://www.cancer.org/healthy/eat-healthy-get-active/take-control-your-weight/calorie-counter-calculator.html) say 2159 calories per day

[www.calorieking.com](http://www.calorieking.com/interactive-tools/how-many-calories-should-you-eat/) says between 1800 and 2000 calories per day

[www.livestrong.com](https://www.livestrong.com/30-day-fitness-challenge/register/?overlay=1&goal=0&gender=male&age=19&weight=122&feet=5&inches=10&activity=1.2) says 1890 calories a day

The range seems pretty large. Which figure seems most accurate?

Comment: Those estimates vary by only 16% at the extremes.Your personal deviation from whatever data they're using could easily be more than that. As for which one is most accurate, have you read those web sites to find out where they get their data and how they calculate their numbers?

Comment: Calorie needs does vary.  Track your weight and calorie intake and see what is your steady state.  I weigh more than you and my body only needs about 1400 calories a day.

Comment: Could you elucidate on how you tracked your weight and calorie intake to arrive at your steady state of 1400 cals/day? What's your gender, height, age, and activity level?